# How to add attribute to the result of mongoose query before res.status(200).send(result);

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to build a CRUD API that query a mongodb. I want to add another attribute (temperature) to the query result before sending it back to the client. Particularly, I would like to do something where the arrow pointed in the code below.

```
app.get('/items/:name', function (req, res) {
    console.log("get items by name");
    Item.find({ name: req.params.name }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err.message);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(result); // <<<<====== Here
        }
    });
});
```

How can I achieve this function? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think this below way to help you:

```
app.get('/items/:name', function (req, res) {
    console.log("get items by name");
    Item.find({ name: req.params.name }, function (err, result) {
        result = {
           temperature: yourTemperatureValue,
           ...result
        } // <<<<====== Here
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err.message);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(result); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately result is an array of objects and result is not iterable.

Comment: @NullNull and object of this array have temperature attribute?

Comment: the Item.find will return an array of items with the same name. and I want to add an attribute to each of them.

Comment: @NullNull And you have the value of temperature's attribute? Example array or temperature like [15oC, 20oC, 25oC]